# openconnect - I can ping a website but can't wget or access by browser

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, ping

I need to access the VPN of my university. On their website they provide the following solution:

1. install openconnect
2. install vpnc
3. login to vpn via:

   ```
   # openconnect --script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script vpn.example-university.edu
   ```
4. Enter credentials

Everything works fine, I can successfully login and stay connected. Now there is something weird going on: I can ping websites but can't access them neither via webbrowser nor `wget`.

The script changes my `resolv.conf` and adds one domain (university domain) and one nameserver (university ip) to it. I do not have any iptable configuration (All policies are ACCEPT).

On Ubuntu it just worked fine, but now I am using arch linux.

Comment: What does the routing table look like?

Comment: can you post the results of a traceroute and telnet to port 80